# How to point to the correct XML inferface parameter of IXMLNode type in procedure

Tags: xml, delphi, data-binding

I'm building a program in Delphi that loads/saves its files in XML format. However if a major change in the parameters occur I'm making new save version of the files. In my case I'm moving from version 1.03 to 1.05. So my load procedure is now updated from 1.03 to 1.05 and the binding file is also updated, but the problem is that some functions inside the load function are defined externally and then they don't know which IXML parameter to take into account.
Example:

```
  xMat := Root.Materials;
  SetLength(ArMat, xMat.Count);
  for I := 0 to xMat.Count-1 do
    with Model.Materials do begin
      ArMat[I] := AddSafe(xMat[I].Name, '', Materials);
      if (Steels[ArMat[I]].Name <> xMat[I].Name) then begin
        ArMat[I] := AddSteel(TSteel.Create);
        Steels[ArMat[I]].LoadFromXML(xMat[I);
      end;
    end;
```

so LoadFromXML is defined in another unit:

```
procedure TSteel.LoadFromXML(XML: IXMLSteel);
begin
  Name := XML.Name;
  Standard := XML.Standard;
  Elasticity := XML.Elasticity_modulus;
  Poisson := XML.Poisson_ratio;
  Shear := XML.Shear_modulus;
  Thermal := XML.Thermal_elongation;
  Mass := XML.Mass;
  fy := XML.Yeild_strength;
  fu := XML.Ultimate_strength;
end;
```

and IXMLSteel parameter should be loaded with correct binding parameters:

```
{ IXMLSteel }

  IXMLSteel = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{095C1F0C-8F41-4B25-BFC4-9C0F7DC2DAC7}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Name: WideString;
    function Get_Standard: WideString;
    function Get_Elasticity_modulus: Single;
    function Get_Poisson_ratio: Single;
    function Get_Shear_modulus: Single;
    function Get_Thermal_elongation: Single;
    function Get_Mass: Single;
    function Get_Yeild_strength: Single;
    function Get_Ultimate_strength: Single;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: WideString);
    procedure Set_Standard(Value: WideString);
    procedure Set_Elasticity_modulus(Value: Single);
    procedure Set_Poisson_ratio(Value: Single);
    procedure Set_Shear_modulus(Value: Single);
    procedure Set_Thermal_elongation(Value: Single);
    procedure Set_Mass(Value: Single);
    procedure Set_Yeild_strength(Value: Single);
    procedure Set_Ultimate_strength(Value: Single);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Name: WideString read Get_Name write Set_Name;
    property Standard: WideString read Get_Standard write Set_Standard;
    property Elasticity_modulus: Single read Get_Elasticity_modulus write Set_Elasticity_modulus;
    property Poisson_ratio: Single read Get_Poisson_ratio write Set_Poisson_ratio;
    property Shear_modulus: Single read Get_Shear_modulus write Set_Shear_modulus;
    property Thermal_elongation: Single read Get_Thermal_elongation write Set_Thermal_elongation;
    property Mass: Single read Get_Mass write Set_Mass;
    property Yeild_strength: Single read Get_Yeild_strength write Set_Yeild_strength;
    property Ultimate_strength: Single read Get_Ultimate_strength write Set_Ultimate_strength;
  end;
```

The idea is when I open 1.03 version file to use the IXMLSteel from the 1.03 binding and logically when 1.05 file comes to use the IXMLSteel from 1.05. I have their definition on two places now (with different unique GUID). It seems that Delphi doesn't know which one to use and gives error:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'odr_model_1_05_binding.IXMLSteel' and
>   'odr_model_1_03_binding.IXMLSteel'

Can I somehow point the correct XML type to the LoadFromXML procedure depending on which version the file is?

thank you for the help

Comment: You say LoadFromXML is in a different unit but you don't make it clear whither you can edit that unit. If you can I would suggest overloading the LoadFromXMLFile function with the two possible parameter types. The error message tells you which types to use.

Comment: instead of passing IXMLSteel, pass as IXMLNode and test the interface with the IS function. (eg if XML is odr_model_1_05_binding.IXMLSteel then Loadv105(XML as odr_model_1_05_binding.IXMLSteel)...

Comment: @whosrdaddy you should use the [`SysUtils.Supports()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function when converting one interface to another, don't use `is` and `as`. Those are fine for object types, but not interface types